# How can I make Applescript tell Messages to send a message as an SMS message, using Text Forwarding?

Tags: text, sms, applescript, message, imessage

Currently, it is sending out the message as an *iMessage*, and I have to go through each message, one at a time, and resend them as a *SMS* (defeats the purpose).

```
    set theSpeel to "" & first word of theName & "" & theExp & ""

    tell application "Messages"

        activate
        send theSpeel to buddy theNumber of service 1

    end tell
```

Comment: S.O. tip: A piece of code of what you've tried so far will encourage people to help you. People out there love code.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for anyone else wanting to do the same, you can save the following Applescript as sendSMS.app:

```
on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage}
    tell application "Messages"
        send targetMessage to buddy targetBuddyPhone of service "SMS"
    end tell
end run
```

Running `osascript sendSMS.app 5551234 "Hello"`in terminal sends "Hello" to number 5551234 as an SMS (given that you have set up your phone with SMS forwarding to your Mac). [Hat tip](https://liddlethoughts.wordpress.com/2015/03/23/programmatically-sending-an-imessage-from-osx/).